# How to fix SequelizeConnectionError for postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

So I cloned a repo that has a Postgres DB setup that doesn't allow me to seed the data or run the app. I am not sure what exactly I need to edit for it to run on my system. I could provide more information but I am unsure of what. I am also running ubuntu if that makes any difference.

Here is the error:

```
seeding...
ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: password authentication failed for user "user"
    at Client._connectionCallback (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/postgres/connection-manager.js:184:24)
    at Client._handleErrorWhileConnecting (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:305:19)
    at Client._handleErrorMessage (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:325:19)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at /home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:114:12

    at Parser.parse (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:40:17)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11) {
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
  parent: error: password authentication failed for user "user"
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {
    length: 99,
    name: 'error',
    severity: 'FATAL',
    code: '28P01',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'auth.c',
    line: '329',
    routine: 'auth_failed'
  },
  original: error: password authentication failed for user "user"
      at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)
      at Parser.handlePacket (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)
      at Parser.parse (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)
      at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/user/Documents/projects/app/server/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)
      at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
      at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
      at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:290:11)
      at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:224:10)
      at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:182:23) {

    length: 99,
    name: 'error',
    severity: 'FATAL',
    code: '28P01',
    detail: undefined,
    hint: undefined,
    position: undefined,
    internalPosition: undefined,
    internalQuery: undefined,
    where: undefined,
    schema: undefined,
    table: undefined,
    column: undefined,
    dataType: undefined,
    constraint: undefined,
    file: 'auth.c',
    line: '329',
    routine: 'auth_failed'
  }
}
closing db connection
db connection closed
```

Comment: It is very informative. You run with the wrong credentials for the DB.

Comment: How do I run it with the right ones?